# Django Form not rendering

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following form in forms.py:

```
class ContractForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    start_date = forms.DateField()
    end_date = forms.DateField()
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    client = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Client.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContractForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['client'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Client.objects.filter(user=user))
        clients = Client.objects.filter(user = user)
        for client in clients:
            print client
```

And in my view the method looks like this:

```
def addContract(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/contractManagement/login/?next=%s' % request.path)
else:   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        contractForm = ContractForm(request.POST)
        title = request.POST['title']
        start_date = request.POST['start_date']
        end_date = request.POST['end_date']
        description = request.POST['description']
        client = request.POST['client']
        user = request.user
        contract = Contract(title,start_date,end_date,description,client,user)
        contract.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('../../accounts/profile/')
    else:
        user = request.user
        print user.username
        contractForm = ContractForm(user)
        return render_to_response('newcontract.html', {'contractForm': contractForm})
```

But the form won't render in the browser. All that shows up is the submit button. My HTML looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
{% if contractForm.errors %}
<p style="color: red;">
    Please correct the error{{ contractForm.errors|pluralize }} below.
</p>
{% endif %}
<form method="POST" action="">    
    <table>
        {{ contractForm.as_table }}
    </table> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form> 
 </body>
</html>
```

So why won't the form render?

---

**EDIT**
I have got rid of the custom client field requiring the user and it still won't render. I thought this might help. 
So a form could use this class:

```
class ContractForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    start_date = forms.DateField()
    end_date = forms.DateField()
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    client = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Client.objects.all())
```

Comment: Does the form work fine when you just do a GET on the page?  Also, instead of your auth check at the beginning, check out the login_required decorator that will do it for you.

Comment: @sdolan no it doesn't have any impact on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the name of the forms in the view. It now looks like this

```
form = ContractForm(user=request.user)
```

And it works.

Answer (score 2):

The `queryset` argument to `forms.ModelChoiceField` should be a queryset. It should read:

```
self.fields['client'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Client.objects.filter(user=user))
```

And you have to declare it in your form first before overriding it in the `__init__()` method:

```
class ContractForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    client = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Client.objects.all())
```

Comment: Either way, Amaud is right - querysets have to be actual QuerySet objects.  Since your problem is ongoing, can you update your code sample to reflect the current state of your ContactForm class?

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few things wrong here, in addition to the QuerySet issue Arnaud points to.

Firstly, when you instantiate the form in response to a GET, you do `contractForm = ContractForm(user)`. But the first parameter to a form instantiation (as you correctly do in the POST) is the posted data - and you haven't altered the form's `__init__` signature.

Secondly, in the `__init__` itself, you reference a `user` variable: but you haven't actually got that variable from anywhere. You can't magically reference variables without receiving them from somewhere.

So to fix those errors, you need to change the init method as follows:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user')
    super(ContractForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['client'].queryset=Client.objects.filter(user=user)
```

and instantiate the form in the view like this:

```
contractForm = ContractForm(user=request.user)
```

Thirdly, although this is not related to the problem you post, you will never see any errors on this form, because you don't check it is valid in the POST section - you need to check `if contractForm.is_valid()`, and if not fall through to the final `render_to_response` (which needs to be unindented one level).

Also, you are ignoring the whole point of having a form, by setting your model direct from `request.POST`. You should be using the contents of `contractForm.cleaned_data` to create the Contract instance.

And finally, you should investigate whether a ModelForm would meet your needs better.

Comment: It's still not rendering the form.