# Django form not rendering in HTML

Tags: html, django, forms

---

I have a form that isn't rendering and I can't figure out why. The only thing showing is submit button. I created the form having followed the methodology described [here](https://hellowebbooks.com/news/tutorial-setting-up-a-contact-form-with-django/), [here](https://wsvincent.com/django-contact-form/) and [here](https://www.pydanny.com/overloading-form-fields.html).

I looked at solutions for the problem (listed below amongst others) but they havent helped.

[django-forms not rendering errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383768/django-forms-not-rendering-errors)

[django form not rendering in template. Input fields doesn't shows up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328586/django-form-not-rendering-in-template-input-fields-doesnt-shows-up)

[Django Form not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987824/django-form-not-rendering)

[Django Form not rendering - following documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739055/django-form-not-rendering-following-documentation)

The html is app_core/index.html which extends another- landing_page/base.html

The html:

```
{% extends 'landing_page/base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}
{% load bootstrap %}

{%block content %}
<div id="contactus" class="container-fluid">

<br>

<div class="container text-center">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-left">
            <center><h3>{% trans 'Contact Us' %}</h3>
            <p>{% trans 'We are at your disposal 365 days 24 hours a day. When you think of languages think of Milingual.
                            Languages are not studied, they are lived!' %}</p></center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class ="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-left">
        <center><h1>Contact Us</h1><center>

        <form id="contactus-form" action="{% url 'contact' %}"method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}

            <br/>
            <div class="form-actions">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-center">Send</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div>

    </div>

</div>
```

```
{%endblock content %}
```

The Views.py

```
from django.core.mail import BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ContactForm
#ContactUs
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
    form = ContactForm()
else:
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        whoareyou = form.cleaned_data['whoareyou']
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        try:
            send_email(subject, message, whoareyou, from_email, ['thiswaysouth@gmail.com'])
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return redirect('success')
return render(request, "/index.html", {'form': form})


def success(request):
    return HttpResponse('Success! Thank you for your message.')
```

The form.py

```
from django import forms


class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    WHOAREYOU_CHOICES = (
        ('Teacher', 'Teacher'),
        ('Student', 'Student'),
        ('Venue', 'Venue'),
        ('Business', 'Business'),
        ('Other', 'Other')
    )
    whoareyou = forms.ChoiceField(choices=WHOAREYOU_CHOICES, required=True)
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(required=True)
    from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)
```

And the urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from .views import *
from app_core import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', IndexPage, name='index'),
    # setting session city
    url(r'^get-city-session$', GetCitySession, name='get-city-session'),
    url(r'^set-city-session$', SetCitySession, name='set-city-session'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^success/$', views.success, name='success'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended having a very simple solution that I failed to notice simply because of my naivete and newness to programming. The above code was and is perfectly correctly but I neglected to add crucial line of code in the ContactForm code in form.py. At the end of the form I was simply to add the following lines and it rendered perfectly:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    WHOAREYOU_CHOICES ...

    class Meta:
        fields =('whoareyou','name','phone_number','from_email','subject','message')
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put your code inside blocks otherwise it doesn't know where to put it when you extend. In your base.html, you can do something like

```
{% block body %}
{% endblock %}
```

And then in your index.html page, you need to surround everything that you want to appear in that spot in your base.

```
{% block body %}
  ... Code goes here ...
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: its already in a in block. I had neglected to add it here. the rest of the html is rendering perfectly. Just the form that isn't